# Как получить сишный file descriptor из Delphi

Tags: delphi

Имеется динамическая библиотека, в которой есть функция, требующая на вход file descriptor из языка си:

```
int some_func (int fd, ...)
```

Например, как результат вызова функции [_wopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen?view=msvc-170).

Вопрос: как вызвать данную функцию из Delphi, точнее, как получить правильный дескриптор для неё? Обычные handle, полученные в результате вызова CreateFile() она не принимает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляете описание функции:

```
function _wopen(const filename: PWideChar; const oflag, pmode: Integer): Integer;
  cdecl; external 'msvcrt.dll';
```

и пользуетесь ей как обычно.

P.S. И не забудьте в конце закрыть хендл, если ваша библиотека этого не делает.

Comment: А можно где-то найти список вот этих привязок?.. А то я описание самих функций в хедерах нашёл, а вот куда они привязаны - нет (я про это: `external 'msvcrt.dll'`).

Comment: @Alekcvp Чтоб вот прямо списком - не знаю, но у любой библиотеки можно посмотреть список экспортируемых функций. DependencyWalker, objdump и прочие утилиты с этим помогут. Можно просканировать все системные dll и составить себе список.